# Член предложения (1)

Tags: синтаксис

Каким членом предложения является слово берёз?

Пар ещё не остывших влажных низин поднялся на уровень древесных вершин и замёрз, рассыпался на свободных от снега ветках берёз.

По какой схеме правильно определять?

На мой взгляд, это дополнение, т. к. ставил вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Ветках (чьих?) берез или ветках (чего?) берез. Можно также сказать: на березовых ветках.

Это **несогласованное определение,** которое имеет **дополнительное значение "часть целого".**

В таких случаях второстепенный член можно назвать **определительным дополнением или дополнительным определением.**