# Как различить определение, дополнение, обстоятельство?

Tags: члены-предложения

Что определяет *определение* и что дополняет *дополнение*? С определением все понятно: оно относится к слову с предметным значением и называет его признак.

С дополнением хуже: этот второстепенный член определяется нечётко, а именно: дополнение отвечает на вопросы косвенных падежей. Но на те же вопросы могут отвечать несогласованные определения и обстоятельства.

Есть более точное определение: дополнение называет предмет, на который распространяется действие или по отношению к которому проявляется признак.

Аналогично обстоятельство относится к слову со значением действия или признака, называя различные внешние особенности проявления этого признака.

Вот пример [IV. Составление плана | studfiles.ru](http://www.studfiles.ru/preview/3873862/page:6/)

> Какие вопросы можно задать от главных слов к зависимым? (Дверь какая?
>   балконная; дверь какая? на балкон, дверь куда? на балкон.) Последний
>   вопрос возможен, но он не выражает грамматического значения
>   определения: главное слово не обозначает ни действия, ни признака. Мы
>   рассматриваем подобные случаи как несогласованные определения.

**Получается, что основным критерием является главное слово**: если это предмет, то падежная форма является определением, а если мы считаем падежную форму дополнением или обстоятельством, то **главное слово должно быть связано с действием или проявлением признака.** Тогда "ветка березы" — это согласованное определение, но не дополнение, — в противном случае в слове "ветка" надо искать проявление  признака, отнесенного к "березе".

И вывод.

Для различения функции падежных форм надо составить чёткое определение второстепенных членов и применять его на практике, не ссылаясь при этом на падежные вопросы.

Или я ошибаюсь?

Answer (score 1):

Видимо, вопрос [424554](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/424554) побудил вас провести это исследование. Там речь шла о предложении:

> Пар [...] рассыпался на свободных от снега ветках *берёз*.

Боюсь, что на "школьном" уровне эта задача не имеет решения. Не имеет она также и практической ценности - такую "грамматику" в школе изучать незачем: спор "определение или дополнение" здесь носит совершенно схоластический характер, он никак не способствует ни пониманию текста, ни даже повышению грамотности.

Любой ответ (и *определение*, и *дополнение*) здесь должен приниматься как правильный - на это косвенно указывает нам научная грамматика ([Значения родительного падежа в присловной позиции](http://rusgram.narod.ru/2680-2696.html#2689)):

> 2) **Определительно-субъектное** значение род. п. обнаруживает тогда, когда определительное значение сочетается в нем со значениями того, кто действует, кто обладает свойством, предметом (в широком смысле слова), кто (что) имеет отношение к кому-чему-л., включает кого-что-л. в свой состав, от кого (чего) что-л. исходит, кем (чем) производится. [...] Элемент субъектного значения заключен также в род. п. существительных, называющих обладателя: книга товарища, руки матери, хвост белки, крыша дома, деталь машины; день января, весна года [...]

То есть в слове "берёз" (в словосочетании "на ветках берёз") содержится **и определительное** значение, **и субъектное** значение. Но как это перевести на "школьный язык" (и надо ли)?

**И вывод**: для различения синтаксической функции падежных форм для начала надо внимательно изучить раздел Русской Грамматики [Синтаксис формы слова (обзор)](http://rusgram.narod.ru/2680-2696.html).

Comment: Спасибо за информацию, обязательно ознакомлюсь по возможности. В то же время я думаю, что любая тема (в том числе и школьный разбор предложения) может иметь ясное  ( а не только академическое) описание  на понятном для этого уровня языке  и  с использованием доступной для школьного  возраста терминологии. В противном случае не стоит вообще занимать детей манипуляциями, которые они делают механически и не слишком понимают.

Comment: Скорее всего, сложно объяснить третьекласснику, что такое определительно-субъектное значение, но наверное можно рассказать ему о  принципиальном отличии дополнения от определения, хотя бы сами термины эти объяснить.  Можно-то можно,  да только  легче отмахнуться и сказать, что существует такой зверь -  полудополнение-полуопределение, о котором много рассуждать себе дороже. Вопросы же на эту тему задаются постоянно, а ясного для всех заинтересованных лиц ответа  всё-таки нет.

Comment: Вы правы, ответа нет. И я так считаю (что в школе ответа нет). И практически это означает, что ошибку ученикам здесь засчитывать нельзя. Хотя лучше, наверное, и вовсе не ставить такие задачи перед третьеклассниками...

Comment: Пока ответа нет, но он должен быть. Это просто задача, которую никто не хочет решить.  Нужно начать с четких определений: что такое определение, что такое дополнение и есть ли между ними принципиальные различия. А потом подумать над вопросом: ветка (чего?) березы - хорошо звучит, ветка (какая?) березовая - тоже неплохо, а вот "береза ветки" - не подойдет.  А вот другой пример: ,  стихи (кого? чьи?) автора, автор (чего?) стихов, но автор (чей?)  стихов - не годится. В общем, вполне можно додумать картинку до конца и объяснить смысл двойных вопросов и двойной роли на уровне 10+